# Proper way to use useSelect

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

I am using useSelect to get available image sizes and then I want to check that the images actually have these sizes as there may have been some custom image sizes added.

What I have done is working but I am concerned the implementation is incorrect as it is the first time I am using useSelect.

```
import { compose } from "@wordpress/compose";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { isBlobURL } from "@wordpress/blob";
import {
    MediaPlaceholder,
    BlockControls,
    MediaUpload,
    MediaUploadCheck,
    InspectorControls,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import {
    Toolbar,
    IconButton,
    PanelBody,
    SelectControl,
} from "@wordpress/components";
const { useSelect } = wp.data;

export function Edit(props) {


    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    const {
        attributes: { id, alt, url },
        setAttributes,
    } = props;

    
    const imageSizes = useSelect(
        (select) => {
            return {
                imageSizes: select("core/editor").getEditorSettings().imageSizes,
                image: id ? select("core").getMedia(id) : null,
            };
        },
        [id]
    );

    const onSelectImage = ({ id, url, alt }) => {
        setAttributes({ id, url, alt });
    };

    function getImageSizes() {
        const { image } = imageSizes;
        if (!image) return [];
        let options = [];
        const sizes = image.media_details.sizes;
        for (const key in sizes) {
            const size = sizes[key];
            const imageSize = imageSizes.imageSizes.find((size) => size.slug === key);
            if (imageSize) {
                options.push({
                    label: imageSize.name,
                    value: size.source_url,
                });
            }
        }
        return options;
    }

    return (
        <>
            {url && !isBlobURL(url) && (
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody title="Image Settings">
                        {id && (
                            <SelectControl
                                label="Image size"
                                options={getImageSizes()}
                                onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
                            />
                        )}
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            )}
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <div>
                    {url ? (
                        <>
                            <img src={url} alt={alt} />
                            {isBlobURL(url) && <Spinner />}
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <MediaPlaceholder
                            icon="format-image"
                            onSelect={onSelectImage}
                            onError={onUploadError}
                            accept="image/*"
                            allowedTypes={["image"]}
                        />
                    )}

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Edit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am concerned the implementation is incorrect

If you just wanted to know whether you have correctly used [`useSelect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useselect), then yes, you have — and I would also return the same object as returned by your callback.

However, instead of `const imageSizes = useSelect( ... )`, I'd just do `const { image, imageSizes } = useSelect( ... )`, i.e. unpack the properties, and then I would not need the `const { image } = imageSizes;` and I also would just use `imageSizes` instead of `imageSizes.imageSizes`.

But that's just my personal preference, and one reason is because unpacking would make the code less.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Sally!